# WordPress simple Url Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to implement simple url rewriting:

this link:  `http://www.mysite.it/DN1`

should load `http://www.mysite.it/chi-siamo`

I have inplemented this code in function.php file of the theme:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic1() {
    echo("ciao4");
  add_rewrite_rule('^DN1/', '/chi-siamo/', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic1');
```

but when I load the link, I get the 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme's `functions.php` is not the best place to do these sort of URL rewrites.

> Why?: because in that case WordPress will be fully loaded and then redirected to a new link and then fully loaded again to show the page. That's a lot of delay for a page view.

Instead of that, you may use URL rewrite in `.htaccess` (assuming your web server is Apache):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# YOUR CUSTOM REDIRECT
RewriteRule ^DN1$ http://www.mysite.it/chi-siamo [L,R=301,NC]

# default WordPress rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```